# Maximum filesize per file can FIP service handle

Tags: exception, tooltwist

We got this alert and it appears that the controller server was unable to transfer the file to our production server due to the file too large to be transferred to our Production Server/s:

```
*exception: tooltwist.fip.FipException: File is too large to be downloaded: tomcat/bin/synnexESDClient.2013-04-30.log*
```

Upon checking on the controller's image, the file's size is 84MB:

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 controller controller **84M** Apr 30 23:59 synnexESDClient.2013-04-30.log
```

What is the maximum filesize per file can the FIP service handle to transfer from controller to production server/s?  Or is there a config file for FIP service that we can check?

Comment: The FIPS tag does not refer to "FIP Service".  Mouse over it to see.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain of the maximum size of fip file transfers, but it's probably a power of 2 (32mb, 64mb, etc).

In any case, the purpose of FIP (File Installation Protocol) is to incrementally deploy an application to production servers. Including large log files in the software distribution process is likely to jam up your website updating process, as it is installed to a dozen or more servers (especially when some are on the other side of the country).

First thing, you might want to consider whether you really want to deploy a log file from the Controller to production servers (what is the Controller doing that creates that log file, and why do you want it on production servers?).

If you really need to copy that file to production servers, I suggest you do it independently to the software and web files installation process. To do this, include the log file in the exclusion list for fip and then copy it by hand.